# conversion of 24 hours clock in 12 hours JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

i want to make an analogue clock which displays system time. My code is working perfectly but the only issue i am having is that i want to show time in 12 Hours format but its showing in 24 hours format.

```
 void setCurrentTime() {
       Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
// Set current hour, minute, and second
this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
paintClock();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: sorry just edited the post , method for the current time

Comment: If you can, use the [new Data Time library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) that's in Java 8 instead of the old `Calendar` class. The new library is better and easier to use in a lot of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar.HOUR` instead of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

---

From Javadocs for [Hour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) :

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11)

From Javadocs for [HOUR_OF_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) :

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock.

Comment: Thanku for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, from your use of JavaFX, that you're also using Java 8:

Let the venerable `Calendar` class retire. Use `java.time`:

```
LocalTime currTime = LocalTime.now();
this.hour   = currTime.get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM);
this.minute = currTime.getMinute();
this.second = currTime.getSecond();
```